# insert date in sqlite database from java

Tags: java, sqlite

My frontend is java and backend (database) is sqlite.

When I select date from `JDateChooser`, I want to store date and time like this:

```
Saturday, January 17, 2015 3:44:12 PM
```

So how do I do this ?

I don't know what value I should write in the `dateFormatString` property of `jDateChooser` so as to get my above formatted date and time.

I have four columns in the table. One column name is "Date" and its datatype is `DATETIME`.

In this column i want to store above formatted date and time.

For date and time insertion, I wrote the following code:

```
try
{   String sql = "insert into tbexpense (`No.`, Subject_expense, Cost, Date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txtNo.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txtexpense.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txtcost.getText());
    pst.setString(4, ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText());
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved.");
    Update_table();
}
catch(Exception e)
{   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

Comment: You don't store date with a format. It is not a string. Usually, it's an internal implementation that indicates the time elapsed since a given "zero" date. You only format it when you need to display it, not when you store it.

Comment: Just store the date, storing it as a particular formatted string, will cause you all sorts of problems.

Comment: The format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. Read [this documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) for more information.

Comment: Before storing the date in database, How to format date with name of the days of the week, month, 12-hour clock with AM or PM

Comment: @user3216114 For what purpose? MySQLs `DateTime` format won't accept that.

Comment: As we said, you **don't** do that. You do not format it - it is not a string. You store it as a `Timestamp` object. When you need to `SELECT` it back from the database, you can format it and it will have all the information you need for any format you want.

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to store your date is to store it as a `Timestamp` object. A `TIMESTAMP` column in a database is *not* a string, and it doesn't have a format.

Setting date/timestamp fields using a string is bad practice as there can be ambiguities. JDBC allows you to set it directly as a `java.sql.Date` or a `java.sql.Timestamp` using `PreparedStatemet`'s `setDate()` and `setTimestamp()` respectively.

So you get the date from your `JDateChooser` using `getDate()`, convert it into milliseconds, create a `Timestamp` object from it, and set it using `setTimestamp`.

```
try
{   String sql = "insert into tbexpense (`No.`, Subject_expense, Cost, Date) values (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setString(1, txtNo.getText());
    pst.setString(2, txtexpense.getText());
    pst.setString(3, txtcost.getText());
    pst.setTimestamp(4, new java.sql.Timestamp(jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime()) );
    pst.execute();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Saved.");
    Update_table();
}
catch(Exception e)
{   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
}
```

When you need to display the date that has been stored in the database, you can format it properly using `DateFormatter`. At that point, and only at that point, you convert the `Date` or `Timestamp` object to a string.